Use the next.js Link to another pages return 404
I have a file names "page.js",it's the default page.In the "page.js",I use the Link to link to the "buy.js",but it return 404
It's the code use for link to "buy.js" in the "page.js"
import Buy from "./buy";
<Link href="/buy" className="group rounded-lg border border-transparent px-5 py-4 transition-colors hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:dark:border-neutral-700 hover:dark:bg-neutral-800/30">

It's the "buy.js"
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

export default function Buy()
{
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </main>
    );
}

"buy.js" and "page.js" are both in the ./app directory
This was originally in Chinese, and my translation may have been incorrect. I would like to express my gratitude to all those who have answered my questions

You should read the next.js official documentation.
Defining Routes
Since you are using the app directory, you can configure it like this:
./app/page.js will be your default page (home route /).
Create a subdirectory for buy.js to represent its route.
./app
├── page.js
└── buy
    └── page.js

Move buy.js to ./app/buy/page.js.

If you use app router, you should create route by folder. Nextjs will check page.js in folder to render page. You can see more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes
